# Notating large batch of files

Tags: sql, excel, file, data-warehouse, file-format

I have about 30,000 different files all with different file formats names. I want to put together a list of "unique" files given that the dates/etc. are replaced by generic characters/symbols.

For example:

```
20160105asdf_123456_CODE.txt
```

Would be notated into:

```
YYYYMMDD*_######_XXXX.txt
```

Any ideas on how to do this efficiently on a large scale? I thought about parsing it out per delimiter ("_"), but I'm sure there's something a lot easier out there.

Comment: More information would be helpful to know what you're dealing with. What do you know about these filenames: is there a limited set of formats they could be in, or is the format completely arbitrary? Will they all have the same exact components in their names? Are the components going to have consistent formatting across the dataset? Can you tell these components apart by mutually exclusive rules?

Comment: No obvious "easy" way to do this without more information or a full set of "rules".  For example  all dates will be YYYYMMDD - no YYYYDDMM, MMDDYYYY ?

Comment: Rules: 
1. The format is completely arbitrary but in structured sequence with ("_") as seperator (thus assigning generic coding naming convention). 

2. Dates can be YYYYMMDD OR YYYYDDMM OR MMDDYYYY

Comment: Since dates can be any format, there's no way to assign them a to any specific "template"....

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up sorting the files based on string length, and manually going in to convert it groups at a time... not the most efficient way. But oh well :(